# How to fix error 406 after returning from OData controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, odata, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm looking for a way to use OData controller with ASP.NET MVC4 Web.API

Route is registered in application start using

```
using Microsoft.Data.Edm;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.OData.Builder;
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.Routes.MapODataRoute("odata", "api", GetEdmModel());
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
                );
            config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
        }

        static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
        {
            ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
            return builder.GetEdmModel();

        }
 }}
```

OData Controller:

```
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.OData;
using System.Web.Http.OData.Query;
using System.Collections;

public class ODController : ODataController
{

    public class Poco
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
    }

    public IEnumerable Get(ODataQueryOptions queryOptions)
    {
        return new Poco[] {
    new Poco() { id = 1, name = "one", type = "a" },
    new Poco() { id = 2, name = "two", type = "b" },
    new Poco() { id = 3, name = "three", type = "c" }
};
    }
```

Accessing url  http://localhost:52216/admin/API/OD  returns  406 Not accepted error.
Debugger shows that controller is hit. Error occurs after returning from controller.
Hwo to fix this so that OData controller can used in Web API in MVC4?

Comment: 1) Are you sure that you need `using System.Web.Http.OData;` and not `using System.Web.OData;`? OData V4 require `using System.Web.OData;`. See the controller code of [the example](http://www.odata.org/blog/how-to-use-web-api-odata-to-build-an-odata-v4-service-without-entity-framework/). 2) Additionally you have to fill `builder` inside of `GetEdmModel` before the line `return builder.GetEdmModel();`. See the code of `WebApiConfig.cs` in the same example. 3) you should use `AsQueryable()` and replace `IEnumerable` to `IQuerable<Poco>`.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to fix the issues. samples you pointed use hard-coded types. Data columns are defined at runtime before jqgrid table is opened based on user selections  It looks like MVC OData requires types to be defined at application startup to create model. So OData cannot used. I will continue to use jqgrid native json format for data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mix the webapi and webapi for odata. It's better to read to the [samples and tutorials](http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#01-02-getting-started) first.

From your mentioned, I can't understand why you expect that OData can serialize a fly POCO list based on one empty Edm model.

Please try this:

Use your POCO class to build the model

```
ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
builder.EntitySet<Poco>("Do");
return builder.GetEdmModel();
```

Make sure the controller class naming convention. It should be `[EntitySetName] + "Controller"`

Remove the Web API Route.

<del>`config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(..);`</del>

Then, the request Uri should return what you want. Thanks.